# Updating an EntityFramework Record with relating new records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am trying to use one attach to the EF to update all the records I need.

```
public void UpdateSale(Sale s)
    {
        Context.Sales.Attach(s);
        Context.Entry(s).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Lets Say like so. The above code gives me an error because it says the primary keys I am trying to add already exist(They arent automatically generated yet)

Now Sale has a number of different other Entity Models inside it like:
SavedForm, ProductSale

Now the code calling the UpdateSale is here

```
        public JsonResult AddNewForms(string Anamaka, string NispahB, string Hazaot, string ManufactorerID, string ClientStatus, string TypeFile)
    {
        BL.FormConnectorLogic fcl = new BL.FormConnectorLogic();
        DAL.SavedForm AnamakaForm = MakeSavedForm(Boolean.Parse(Anamaka),"מסמך הנמקה",ClientStatus);
        DAL.SavedForm NispahBForm = MakeSavedForm(Boolean.Parse(NispahB), "נספח ב", ClientStatus);
        DAL.SavedForm HazaotForm = MakeSavedForm(Boolean.Parse(Hazaot), TypeFile, ClientStatus, ManufactorerID);
        var results = new { A = AnamakaForm, N = NispahBForm, H = HazaotForm  };
        return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public DAL.SavedForm MakeSavedForm(bool Authorized, string FormName, string ClientStatus, string ManufactorerID = "")
    {
        DAL.Sale s = (DAL.Sale)Session["SaleSave"];
        DAL.SavedForm sf = new DAL.SavedForm();
         if (Authorized)
         {
            sf = new DAL.SavedForm();
            sf.FormName = new BL.FormConnectorLogic().getFormByName(FormName, ClientStatus, ManufactorerID).FormName;
            sf.DateFormed = DateTime.Now;
            sf.AgentID = s.AgentID;
            sf.Status = "פתוח";
            sf.SaleID = s.ID;
            s.SavedForms.Add(sf);
            new BL.SaleLogic().UpdateSale(s);
            Session["SaleSave"] = s;
            return sf;
        }
        else return null;

}
```

Now I've read up on the State and there is a difference between Added and Modified.
While I can't really seem to tell when I am going to add and when I am going to modify.
Is there anyway to disregard everything and to just shove my whole class and all its relationships to the database?

Comment: You need to know whether you want to add or modify, there is no way for EF to magically work it out. In order to modify you need to know the relevant primary key values, otherwise all you can do is add.

Comment: But isn't it a simple matter of knowing whether the primary ID already exists or not? If it doesn't add and otherwise modify. The thing is, it doesnt logically sit in my head how do I check whether I need to modify or add or when to attach and save if I did.

Comment: It depends what you mean by exists, if you PK was an int it would have a default value of 0, but EF doesn't know whether 0 is a valid PK or not. If YOU can logically tell (e.g. 0 is new records positive is existing record) then you can write code that adds or updates as needed.

Comment: I guess I just had wishful thinking that there is a magical solution for this. Thanks anyway I'll try it as you say.

Comment: Take a look at GraphDiff, a library that fills the gap EF has left in updating disconnected object graphs.